# Event hub Regenerate keys missing parameter "parameters"

Tags: python, azure-eventhub

I'm using new version of azure-mgmt-eventhub v9.0.0 with python. In this version there is a new parameter "parameters".
My working code to rotate keys it's failing with error: "missing parameter parameters".

Working code with version 4.0:

```
key = client.namespace.regenerate_keys(rg_name, namespace_name, some_authorization_rule_name, key_type: 'PrimaryKey')
```

With new version 9.0.0 it should be :

```
key = client.namespace.regenerate_keys(rg_name, namespace_name, some_authorization_rule_name, parameters='PrimaryKey')
```

this gives other error's like has no self token.

Can someone help with the correct use for version 9.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
params = {
    'keyType' : 'PrimaryKey'
}

client.namespaces.regenerate_keys(rg_name,namespace_name,some_authorization_rule_name,parameters=params)
```